# How to add items from a listbox, to text boxes in a separate form in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to create a simple library application in c#.  I am currently trying to create an edit form - the user will click on a book which is displayed in the list box and then open the edit form. When the edit form is opened I want the book details such as author, title etc to be displayed in the relevant text boxes on the edit form. Does anyone have any tips on how I could do this? I am fairly new to this by the way. Here is my code so far:

```
 private void lstBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string currentBook = lstBooks.SelectedItem.ToString();


    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstBooks_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);

        frmEditBook tempEditBook = new frmEditBook();
        tempEditBook.Show();
        frmkeepBookstore.Hide();


    }
```

The book class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace prjBooks
{
class Book
{
    private string isbn;
    private string title;
    private string author;
    private int yearPublished;
    private int numCopies;

    public Book(string theAuthor, string theTitle, string theYearPublished,  string theNumCopies, string theIsbn)
    {
        isbn = theIsbn;
        title = theTitle;
        author = theAuthor;
        setYearPublished(theYearPublished);
        setNumCopies(theNumCopies);
    }

    //getters

    public string getIsbn()
    {
        return isbn;
    }

    public string getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public string getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public int getYearPublished()
    {
        return yearPublished;
    }

    public int getNumCopies()
    {
        return numCopies;
    }

    // setters

    public void setIsbn(string inIsbn)
    {
        isbn = inIsbn;
    }

    public void setTitle(string inTitle)
    {
        title = inTitle;
    }

    public void setAuthor(string inAuthor)
    {
        author = inAuthor;
    }

    public void setYearPublished(string inYearPublished)
    {
        try
        {
            yearPublished = Convert.ToInt32(inYearPublished);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" +
                    e.Message + " Please input a valid year");
        }
    }

    public void setNumCopies(string inNumCopies)
    {
        try
        {
            numCopies = Convert.ToInt32(inNumCopies);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ERROR:" + e.Message
                                + " Please input a number of copies:");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a very long code. Please edit your question and post just necessary code that you have tried so far.

Comment: very long code... what does not work?

Comment: I have edited my code - this is the bit i am currently working on

Comment: In my opinion, you really want to create a class for Book with all of these properties you listed as...  well, as properties.  Then, pass the object book back and forth between the forms.  As an added bonus, you can bind your object properties to the various areas of the form at design time, which means less hand-written code.  This will require no return values, as the object itself is actually updated directly.

Comment: I've got a book class - edited my post

Comment: Any more help here would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not read your code too much, but I respond to your title.
If you want add text from listbox to textbox in separate form, just open form with parameters. Parameters should be textboxes, which you want to use in separate form.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(textBox1);
f2.Show();
```

Separate Form:

```
TextBox x;
public Form2(TextBox y)
{
       InitializeComponent();
       x = y;
}
```

Then you can add text to textbox easily like this:

```
x.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

*Maybe I'm a little confused, from where you want to transmit text.*

**EDIT:**

Perhaps it would be better to give as a parameter listbox

Form1:

```
frmEditBook tempEditBook = new frmEditBook(lstBooks);
tempEditBook.Show();
```

Form2:

```
ListBox listBoxBooks;
public frmEditBook(ListBox lstBooks)
{
      InitializeComponent();
      listBoxBooks = lstBooks;
}

private void frmEditBook_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      textBoxName.Text = listBoxBooks.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

I tried to keep your names of controls.

Comment: I'm geting a few errors with this - frmEditBook f2 = new frmEditBook(txtName); - gives me txtName does not exist in the current context. Whenever I write listbox in the edit form I get similar errors too

Comment: Look at my post again, I edited it. Also I tried to keep your names of controls. Perhaps it would be better to give as a parameter listbox, if you want to read from it in separate Form.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I am getting an error when I add frmEditBook tempEditBook = new frmEditBook(lstBooks). It is saying that frmEditBook does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument. Also listBoxBooks = lstBooks; gives this error - lstBooks does not exist in the current context. I'm nearly getting the hang of this but struggling with these errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Still need help please

Comment: I tried again and it worked perfectly, many thanks for your help! :)